# Run callback if/when image loaded

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to know if looking at an image's `height` property is a reliable way to see if it has already loaded.

Let's say I've got a reference to an image, like this:

```
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
```

If I want to run some code that relies on the image being loaded, I can put it in a callback, and run `img.onload = myCallback;`.

But if the image has already loaded before this code runs, then the callback won't execute.

This is one possible solution:

```
if (img.height && img.height > 0) {
    myCallback();
}
else {
    img.onload = myCallback;
}
```

In other words: run `myCallback` now if the image is already loaded, otherwise wait until it's loaded.

But I have a feeling this code might be fragile... Will it work in all cases? Is there a safer or more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Is the image added to the DOM dynamically (via JavaScript) or is it based on the `<img>` element from the HTML source code?

Comment: In HTML code, in this case. And my JavaScript is run _after_ the img element has been parsed, so it may even have already loaded (especially if it's in the cache), or it might be yet to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `complete` property.  However, I don't think this works reliably in all Firefox versions, so it's good to add your height check as backup:

```
if (img.complete) {
    myCallback();
} else if (img.height && img.height > 0) {
    myCallback();
} else {
    img.onload = myCallback;
}
```

Comment: The `complete` property works in all current browsers - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/MyjMU/1/).

Comment: `myCallback.call(img)` instead of `myCallback()` - we want the `this` value inside the callback to refer to the img element. Otherwise, the callback doesn't know which image has loaded.